# Allow PHP? not working in Expression Engine 2.11 templates

Tags: php, php-errors, ee2.11

Has anyone experienced before having issues with the Allow PHP? option in the Templates not working?

Suddenly, the server stopped recognizing the PHP code and it is now not able to show anything nor using custom PHP code in there.

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not come across this behaviour  myself - when things suddenly appear on otherwise stable systems usually the system itself is not the cause - if you have not changed the site code or the add-on code it is unclear why it would stop working.

I would check to see if there has (for example) been a change in your server environment - such as a change in php version being run? There have been a few examples of such bumps in php level triggering problems with add-ons (and EE).

HTH

Comment: Thankfully, I found a way to fix it. The PHP was fine but the HTML code was referring in some parts to a  URL that wasn't working properly. I updated it and it worked back again.. Thanks for your help!